# Panel fixed position

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, panel

I have a Panel in a Form and I want it to be in a fixed position on the top of the Form. So, if I scroll down, the panel will always be visible.

Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: ASP.NET, Winforms or WPF? All have panels, can we pick one out?

Comment: To get a good answer to your question you need to specify more details on the issue. Are you using ASP.NET/WPF/Winforms/Silverlight? How does your code look like now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mantain a control position fixed when scrolling a panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957961/mantain-a-control-position-fixed-when-scrolling-a-panel)

Comment: Hmm, not exact duplicate as far as I can see. But i cannot redo a close-vote.

Answer (score 1):

Have two panels, dock fill one to the form, but make sure the floating panel is part of the Forms's control collection, not the dock-filled panel's collection.  Harder to do with the designer sometimes.

Sample Application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  Panel backPanel;
  Panel floatPanel;

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    floatPanel = new Panel();
    floatPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    floatPanel.SetBounds(0, 0, 128, 64);
    this.Controls.Add(floatPanel);

    backPanel = new Panel();
    backPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    backPanel.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(0, 1000);
    this.Controls.Add(backPanel);
  }
}
```

That's for a floating panel that's on top of an existing panel.  Doesn't make a lot of gui sense because what would happen if a control gets scrolled to underneath the floating panel?

If you are looking for the Top panel to just be above the scrolling portion, add the two panels in reverse order with the "top" panel being dock filled to the top so that the top panel isn't placed "behind" the scrolling panel.

Sample Application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  Panel backPanel;
  Panel topPanel;

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    backPanel = new Panel();
    backPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    backPanel.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(0, 1000);
    this.Controls.Add(backPanel);

    topPanel = new Panel();
    topPanel.Height = 64;
    topPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    this.Controls.Add(topPanel);
  }
}
```

Comment: what if I have a BindingNavigator? How can I fixed it on top? Dock property doesn't work.

Comment: @user1051434 Why doesn't it work?  I replace the "topPanel" control with a BindingNavigator control and it worked just fine.  It went to the top of the form, and the scrolling panel is right below it.  This is based on the 2nd example, since it sounds like you aren't trying to "float" a control over a panel.

Comment: @user1051434 The order of things is important, and the designer can get in the way of things here.  My example works because I'm adding the panel (or navbar) *after* I've added the scrolling panel.  Doing it the other way around makes the control go "behind" the other control.  The other way is to play with the `BringToFront()` and `SendToBack()` methods from within the designer, or open up the "View" - "Other Windows" - "Document Outline" window to change the z-order of the controls.

Comment: I have a bindingNavigator into a panel. There is no way to make my bindingNavigator fix to the top of the panel when I scroll.. Have I?

Comment: @user1051434 No, not if they are in the same panel.  The stuff you are scrolling would get hidden at the top by the NavBar.  That's why my sample code puts in the scrolling panel first, followed by the top panel.  Of course, you can put both panels inside a parent panel or a usercontrol, but the rule should be, only items that scroll belong in that scrolling container.  If it doesn't scroll, it does not belong "inside" that container.